# Laravel get all with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I started using laravel a couple of days ago. I have a lot of experience in other frameworks but i'm straggling a bit with the Eloquent ORM and the relationships.

Say that a user has another table holding its stats. I create that relationship. Now the user also has many posts so i declare that too.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function userDynamic()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDynamic', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

At the other models now we have:

```
class UserDynamic extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

And:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }
}
```

I think i have it right this far. Problem comes when trying to retrieve those.
For one user i'm fine cause i cant

```
$user ( get user from auth token)
$user->stats = $user->userDynamic()->first();
$user->posts = $user->posts()->paginate($this->profilePagination);
```

Which is good, i get the user with an attribute stats containing all info and the posts in an attribute posts.

How ever if i'm trying to get all users like below

```
$users = User::with('userDynamic')->active()->notPrivate();
return $users->paginate($this->followersPagination);
```

All the users are returned like so

```
  {
      "id": 26,
      "name": "LL",
      "url": "",
      "personal_quote": "",
      "private": "0",
      "active": "1",
      "user_dynamic": {
        "user_id": 26,
        "following_count": 7,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "posts_count": 0,
        "likes_count": 0
      }
```

How can i change the attribute name that they are assigned ? Instead of user_dynamic to say like stats.

Comment: Just rename the `userDynamic()` function to what ever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're intent on keeping the name of your `userDynamic` relation then you can simply add an alias for that relation:

```
public function stats()
{
    return $this->userDynamic();
}
```

Comment: I see, great!! And what if i wanted to do the same for posts?? How would i call that ?? Also quick question. If i add posts there does that make that another X ( amount of users queries to the DB or does it use JOINs ) ?

Comment: As far as I know eager loading relations (as you're doing here) basically optimises your queries to minimise number of calls to the DB, using joins etc. If you wanted to load posts in at the same time as stats just add it to the `with` method on your eloquent query e.g. `with(['posts', 'stats']` and your related posts will be eager loaded also :)

Comment: Yes managed to find that after a couple of searches. Appreciate it!